# How std::unordered_set correctly detects equal elements if Hash and KeyEqual are based on different subobjects?

Tags: c++, hash, equality, unordered-set

Consider this snippet:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a, b;
};

template<>
struct std::hash<Foo>
{
    constexpr std::size_t operator()(const Foo& obj) const noexcept
    {
        return std::hash<int>{}(obj.a);
    }
};

template<>
struct std::equal_to<Foo>
{
    constexpr bool operator()(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) const noexpect
    {
        return std::equal_to<int>{}(lhs.b, rhs.b);
    }
}
```

Here I'm using different subobjects for `Hash` and `KeyEqual`. If `std::unordered_set` is checking for uniqueness only in the current bucket, then how can it correctly ensure uniqueness in this case?

Comment: `Hash` is required to return the same value for any objects for which `KeyEqual` returns `true`, so there's no risk of finding equal element in different bucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot ensure uniqueness, at all. This is completely undefined behavior.

It is a requirement that if two objects are compared to be equal, the hash function must produce an equal hash value as well. Any other result is undefined behavior. Quoting the C++ standard:

> [unord.req]
>
> Two values k1 and k2 are considered equivalent if the container’s key equality predicate pred(k1, k2) is
> valid and returns true when passed those values. If k1 and k2 are equivalent, the container’s hash function
> shall return the same value for both.